# How to emulate NumPad on TKL keyboard with END, Insert, etc.?

Tags: keyboard, numpad

I wanna buy a TKL keyboard for space, however the NumPad keys are still much faster to type numbers then the inline ones.

[image: Example keyboard.]

The combination <kbd>**PrintScr**</kbd>, <kbd>**Insert**</kbd>, <kbd>**Delete**</kbd>, <kbd>**Home**</kbd>, etc. could be used to emulate the NumPad. How can I achieve it? Or maybe **UIO-JKL-NM,**?

Comment: Have you considered just purchasing an external numpad? That's the input speed you desire with the added ability to put it away when you want to save on physical space.

Comment: Can you tell us for clarification purposes if you want to buy a TKL keyboard which is wired, wireless or for laptop or desktop? And if you bought it already what did you end up buying?

an external numpad wold SEEM to be solving the proberm, but has 2 disadvantages:

[1] it takes up *space*, which the OP specifically mentions as an issue/motivating factor
[2] it can cost an extra usb port. Or forces one to buy an extra USB hub

But if you do NOT type on a plane nor a tiny lecture table, so space is not a problem, external numpad is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) can be used to [reassign keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Install Autohotkey then save the following as `hotkeys.ahk` and double click to run it:

```
Del::1
End::2
PgDn::3
Ins::4
Home::5
PgUp::6
PrintScreen::7
ScrollLock::8
Pause::9
```

<sub><sub>I've not actually tried this, but I believe it should work. I will try it when I am at my machine which has AHK installed</sub></sub>

This will put a little icon in your taskbar next to your clock which, when you want to use those keys normally, can be right-clicked and either `Suspend` or `exit`'ed

[AHK Keylist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)